# Is storing aws cognito JWT key in frontend javascript insecure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I was reviewing a website's javascript files to find an endpoint i wanted,during this i found a line like this.

```js
DASHBOARD_API_Token=eyJraWQiOiJVS2paTnB3SWdBK292QzB3RWdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When i decoded the Above JWT i found entities like kid, username, useremail, iss = http://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{pool-id}

I have read few amazon resources which tell that its possible to fetch aws credentials using the above token. Given that i only have the jwt token what is possible and is it that i have to contact the website to revoke the current token?

Comment: You should probably read this and/or other articles on using JWT tokens to get a firm understanding: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: @JarredOlson your comment made no sense to what i asked, i know what a json web token is, as a pentester i also know what kind of algorithm verification failures it has in some implementation to achieve authentication bypasses.

Answer (score 13):

Well, AWS Cognito is quite an interesting beast when it comes to its JWT tokens and what you can do with them.

Firstly, when you authenticate the user against Cognito User Pool, you get 3 different tokens: `AccessToken`, `IdToken`, and `RefreshToken`. Both `AccessToken` and `IdToken` are valid for exactly 1 hour (and you can't change it). This is why you get `RefreshToken`, which you can use to get new pair of `AccessToken` and `IdToken` by calling, for example, [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference//API_InitiateAuth.html). `RefreshToken` is by default valid for 30 days, but you can change it in the settings of your Cognito User Pool.

#### AccessToken

This is the most powerful token that is given by Cognito. If you possess a valid `AccessToken`, you can call several quite sensitive Cognito APIs.

One very surprising example is that you can call [DeleteUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteUser.html) API by providing `AccessToken` and it will *completely* remove your account from Cognito User Pool. The "nicest" thing here is that app developer can't stop you from doing it if you've got a valid `AccessToken`. AWS devs are [saying](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=753959) that "its by design". That was one of the strongest reasons why we decided not to pass Cognito Access Token onto the application frontend.

Speaking of the payload of `AccessToken`, the only potentially sensitive claim is the `client_id`, which contains the Cognito Client Id, which was used to authenticate the user. If this client does not have a client secret (which should probably be considered a security flaw in the first place), then the `client_id` can be used to call quite wide range of Cognito APIs. However, Cognito considers `client_id` to be public information. All other claims are considered public, you can see the full list of claims [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html).

#### IdToken

Contains the information about the player. It *may* contain some personal information about the player depending on what standard claims and custom attributes were configured in your Cognito User Pool, however it is also possible to suppress or override those claims using [Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html). Using this trigger allows one to hide or mask player attributes, which are considered sensitive and should not appear in `IdToken`.

As far as I'm aware, you cannot user `IdToken` to call Cognito APIs.

#### RefreshToken

Can only be used to request new `AccessToken` and `IdToken`, cannot be used to call Cognito APIs. In our particular use case we had to avoid passing `RefreshToken` to the app frontend, since it can be used to get `AccessToken` against public Cognito API (meaning that we cannot stop the user from doing that).

#### Using Cognito tokens to get AWS credentials

This is only possible if Cognito User Pool has been explicitly integrated with Cognito Identity Pool (which assumes that app developers knew what they were doing). When you exchange your Cognito JWT tokens, you get temporary AWS credentials with permissions bounded to a specific IAM role configured in Cognito Identity Pool. It is completely legitimate flow and intended behaviour. Moreover, if Cognito Identity Pool is configured to allow unauthenticated access, you can even get temporary AWS credentials without having Cognito JWT tokens (but those will be tied to another, presumably, more restrictive IAM role).

#### Using Cognito tokens with API Gateway

AWS API Gateway resources can be [integrated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) with Cognito User Pools. Depending on how the integration is done, you can use either an `AccessToken` or `IdToken` from the integrated Cognito User Pool.

#### Revoking the tokens

You can revoke all tokens issued for your account in Cognito User Pool by calling [GlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html) API and providing a valid `AccessToken`. As this API is public, you don't need to contact the website if you possess a valid `AccessToken`.

Comment: Not OP but that was an interesting read. How do you prevent access and refresh tokens being returned?

Comment: @Ravenscar in our use case we created an intermediary API Gateway + Lambda layer, which transmitts the requests from the client to Cognito, but also 'signs' the requests using Cognito Client Id and Client Secret. So the client only talks to API Gateway and backend Lambda talks to Cognito on client's behalf, client does not know Cognito client id and client secret. Lambda removes AccessToken and RefreshToken from Cognito response when the client is authenticated.

Comment: thanks for the info. We are thinking of using API Gateway as well. We don't want to deliver the refresh token to the web client as there is no way to store it securely, so instead we want to use an http only secure cookie which can be used against the APIG which in turn will retrieve the new id token from cognito.

Comment: I have discovered that if I unselect the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` in the "App client setting -> OAuth 2.0 -> Allowed OAuth Scopes" section then the access token cannot be used to call the AWS user pool APIs. This stops the user from calling DeleteUser, but also stops other uses such as the ones working with attributes. The userinfo endpoint can still be called with the token though: `https://{domain}.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userinfo`. I believe this way the access token can be used for private APIs.

Comment: @Ravenscar thanks very much for the hint, very useful to know!

Comment: @DmitryDeryabin so if I have backend in java (or generally speaking I am not using lambdas) I should use some key-value database for storing refresh and access tokens on the backend side for each user and pass only idToken to the frontend, right?